# Firestore Security Rules Being Rejected

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was hoping to get some help writing a security rule. It is pretty straight forward but every variation I write for the message rule seems to get rejected. I am looking to say "give read/write access only if you are the sender or receiver of the message".

the basic rules I want to cover with this security:

- a user cannot edit any one else's data
- a user can create and read messages with one other person
- a user cannot access any data if they are not authenticated

error message:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]

What I have so far:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isLoggedIn() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function isSender() {
        return resource != null && resource.data.user._id == request.auth.uid;
    }

    function isReceiver() {
      return resource != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.receiver
    }
      
    match /Users/{userId} {
      //Only authenticated users can access/write data
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /messages/{messageId} {
      // allow read, write: if isLoggedIn() && (isSender() || isReceiver());
        allow read, write: if isLoggedIn() && (resource.data.user._id == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid in resource.data.receiver);
    }    
  }
}
```

the message data structure is like so:

```
id: ""
createdAt:""
index: 1
key: ""
receiver: 
    [0: receiverIDgoeshere]
message: ""
user:
    {_id: ""}
```

query:

```
let query = config.db
.collection(messages)
.where("key", "==", uid)
.orderBy("index", "desc");
if (typeof index === "number") {
    query = query.where("index", ">", index);
}
const chats = await query.get();
```

there is also a listener for incoming messages:

```
const listener = config.db
  .collection(messages)
  .where("key", "==", uid)
  .where("receiver", "array-contains", userId)
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const msgs = snapshot.docChanges().map(({doc, type}) => {
      if (type === "added") {
        return fixData({
          id: doc.id,
          match,
          fromRealTime: true,
          ...doc.data(),
        });
      } else {
        console.log("type is NOT added...");
      }
      return null;
    });
    setMessages(msgs.filter((msg) => msg !== null));
  });
```

and when we add a chat:

```
const fs = config.db;
const doc = fs.collection(messages).doc();
await doc.set(chat);
```

Comment: Can you also add the query for the firebase which is throwing that error?

Comment: @SushanSapaliga updated post with the query

Comment: The `query` is for the sender? and `listener` is for the receiver? Am I right?

Comment: @SushanSapaliga yes you are right. Query is pulling in all of the chats for the sender. The listener is for the receiver to listed for incoming messages.

Comment: Error comes from query or listener? Also rules look fine. Try debugging logging values and simplifying the query.

Answer (score 1):

The query must be updated as follows:

```
let query = config.db
.collection(messages)
.where("key", "==", uid)
.where("user._id", "==", uid)
.orderBy("index", "desc");
//rest is same
```

I don't see any problem with the listener's query.

Comment: I am not trying to fix my query, I am trying to write firebase security to cover my queries.

Comment: The firebase rules you have written are proper. The rules look at your query and give permission to access the data. Try the query I have posted, it won't change the data coming from the database. For more about rules see this [video](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Answer (score 0):

I found that my security rules are fine, I was trying to get too granular with it. All is covered with the above security rules.